# NullPointerException: Collections.binarySearch(List<? extends T>, T, Comparator<? super T>) line: not available

Tags: java, nullpointerexception

This stack error is printed "`Collections.binarySearch(List<? extends T>, T, Comparator<? super T`>) line: not available"
 for this line:

```
int index = Collections.binarySearch(getEmails(), email, determineComparator());
     // Search where to insert
```

I think that emails (returned by `getEmails()`) may be null but it is instantiated with:

```
ArrayList<Email> emails= new ArrayList<Email>();
```

I can provide more details if you indicate what is needed.

Comment: Yeah, I'd like to see more details.  That sounds like a really weird error message.

Comment: Then what methods or declarations do you need?

Comment: Your comparator and your getEmails()

Comment: Let's start with the `getEmails` and `determineComparator` implementations and work from there.

Comment: Can you turn off code optimizations when compiling (so that you can see the line number)?

Comment: Which of these comparators you are using when you get this exception ? Plz show that code

Comment: provide a complete stacktrace please.

Comment: Make sure you are not passing a null reference as an Integer object and autoboxing it into a primitive int type. Those mistakes produce NullPointerExceptions in unsuspecting places.

Comment: When I set a breakpoint I could see that inbox.emails is null even though I initialised it with private Folder inbox=new Folder(); which is supposed to ArrayList<Email> emails= new ArrayList<Email>();

Comment: How would I turn off code optimizations in eclipse?

Answer (score 1):

Your implementation of getEmails() must be returning null.  Collections.binarySearch can handle a null Comparator but not a null list.